# My if statement does the checks but gives no output

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, user-registration

So I have 3 if statements that check to see if the username and password is not empty, to execute my statements and check if the two passwords on my registration form match which is $password and $confirmpassword.

The good part is that it allows the checks to see if the password entered in the password text box matches the repeated password in the confirm password text box and if these do match then the user successfully registers and is directed to the login page after and I can see the person's details in my database with a hashed password.

The bad part is that the other parts of the if statements such as the else will not work. The two issues I have faced is with the last else of the if statement just takes me straight to the "500 Sever Error" page and no matter what I enter on the form - the moment "register" is clicked I go straight to this page. Where as commenting this last else part of the if statement and just checking to see if the messages I put to be displayed, shows once a mismatch of passwords is entered, just gives me a blank page - No error messages.

I've commented things out such as the $message variable and replaced it with echo just to be sure if these are not the ones messing up and just to see some sort of message on the blank screen, but nothing.

I know that at least two of my if statements work, but it feels as though my inner if statement doesn't:

```
if ($stmt->execute()):
    echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
  else:
    echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
```

Here is the code that performs these checks - register.php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

  // $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

//var_dump($password, $confirmpassword);

  if($password == $confirmpassword):

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :password)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hashPassword);

  if ($stmt->execute()):
    echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
    //$message = 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
    //header('Location:loginPage.php');
  else:
    echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
    //$message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
  //else:
    //echo 'Your passwords do not match!';
    //$message = 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';

endif;

endif;

endif;
```

And here is my HTML - registerPage.php:

```
--><form class="col-1-3" action="register.php" method="post">

<fieldset class="register-group">

  <label>
    <br>First Name*
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name*
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
  </label>

  <label>
    Role*
    <select name="role">
      <option value="Student" selected>Student</option>
      <option value="Tutor" selected>Tutor</option>
      <option value="Admin" selected>Admin</option>
    </select>
  </label>

<label>
  Email Address*
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"  value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
</label>

<label>
  Choose a Username*
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
</label>

<label>
  Choose a Password*
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</label>

<label>
  Repeat Password*
  <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
</label>

  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">

</form>
```

I would really appreciate some help with this. Many thanks.

Comment: your posted code doesn't contain the closing `</form>` tag. is that not in your real code?

Comment: look at the server error logs for details about the 500.

Comment: My original code does contain `</form>` it was just something that I didn't include in the snippets of the code by accident.

Comment: Updated the form @Fred-ii- :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mis-match in your `if` structure. You need to move your last `else` after the first `endif`. So like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    //...
    if($password == $confirmpassword):
        //...
        if ($stmt->execute()):
            echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
            //...
        else:
            echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
            //...
        endif;
    else:
        echo 'Your passwords do not match!';
        //...
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the messages now show. :)

Comment: @user3453342 - No problem :)